# What's the right way to create a Clojure function that returns a new sequence based on another sequence?

Tags: clojure

Why do you have to use "first" in get-word-ids, and what's the right way to do this?

```
(defn parts-of-speech []
  (lazy-seq (. POS values)))

(defn index-words [pos]
  (iterator-seq (. dict getIndexWordIterator pos)))

(defn word-ids [word]
  (lazy-seq (. word getWordIDs)))

(defn get-word [word-id]
  (. dict getWord word-id))

(defn get-index-words []
  (lazy-seq (map index-words (parts-of-speech))))

(defn get-word-ids []
  (lazy-seq (map word-ids (first (get-index-words)))))

;; this works, but why do you have to use "first" in get-word-ids?
(doseq [word-id (get-word-ids)]
  (println word-id))
```

Comment: You are using `lazy-seq` wrong, there's a whole idiom you must respect. But mainly, this is low-level stuff and the "right way" would be to combine the existing core functions like `map`, `filter`, `for` etc. to achieve what you want.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992298/clojure-lazy-sequence-usage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: remove all the references to `lazy-seq`.

as for your original question, it is worth explaining even if it's not a idomatic use of lazy-seq. you have to use first because the get-word-ids function is returning a lazy sequence with one entry. that entry is the lazy sequences you are looking for.

looks like this

```
( (word1 word2 word3) )
```

so first returns the sequence you want:

```
(word1 word2 word3)
```

---

It is very likely that the only time you will use `lazy-seq` will be in this pattern:

```
(lazy-seq (cons :something (function-call :produces :the :next :element)))
```

I have never seen lazy-seq used in any other pattern. The purpose of `lazy-seq` is to generate new sequences of original data. If code exists to produce the data then it's almost always better to use something like `iterate` `map`, or `for` to produce your lazy sequence.

Comment: Thank you, Arthur. Well then is iterator-seq being used right in index-words since the Java method is returning an iterator?

Answer (score 1):

This seems wrong:

```
(defn get-index-words []
  (lazy-seq (map index-words (parts-of-speech))))
```

(index-words pos) returns a seq. which is why you need a (first) in get-word-ids.

also map is already lazy, so there's no need to wrap a (map ...) in a lazy-seq, and it would be almost pointless to use lazy-seq around map if map *wasn't* lazy. it would probably be useful if you'd read up a bit more on (lazy) sequences in clojure.