# How to use LazySeq correctly

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

There are a dozen of confusion when I use lazySeq.

Question:

```
(def fib
  (lazy-seq
    (concat [0 1] (map + fib (rest fib))))) ;; It's Ok
(take 10 fib) ;; Bomb
```

Got the error message: *StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.RT.more (RT.java:589)*

And the following solutions works well:

```
(def fib
  (concat [0 1] (lazy-seq (map + fib (rest fib))))) ;; Works well

(def fib
  (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + fib (rest fib)))) ;; Works well
```

Both `concat` and `map` return lazy sequence, why the above programs look like each other but distinguish?

More detailedly, Why the first example (`lazy-seq` wrapping the `concat`) fail but its following example (`lazy-seq` wrapping the `map`) sucess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure lazy sequence usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992298/clojure-lazy-sequence-usage)

Comment: @DominicKexel, actually not the same, my question is focus on the order (or the place) of the `lazy-seq`. In the first example `lazy-seq` locate out of `concat` and bomb in using, but the second `lazy-seq` just wrap the `map` and works well. So I think the order of `lazy-seq` is importante and that is what I want to know, your link does't explain it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to that question explains that very well.

Comment: mikera (whos answer was accepted) sayed "it doesn't really matter which order you put them.". But my question shows the order is significant. How do you think the answer explains well? I read the question and the answer and notice that is not the thing i want, have you ever read my question clearly? @DominicKexel

Comment: @mikera Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @DominicKexel Please look at the first example with patient. I'm not ask for the differences between the cases of using `lazy-seq` and not using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is using `rest` in map operation. Basically when your lazy-seq will call the expression : `(concat [0 1] (map + fib (rest fib)))` to return a ISeq object, the `rest` call on fib will happen (as this is a parameter to `map` it must be executed first and then passed to map and map is lazy but rest is called before we can reach lazyness). `rest` will try to call [`more`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java#L95) on the fib which is a `LazySeq` object and the more will cause the fib lazy seq to get the next ISeq which again involves the execution of whole `concat` operation which involves `rest` and it keeps on going this way until stack is blown away.

You need to use something that doesn't call next right away on the fib, something like `drop`:

```
(def fib
  (lazy-seq
   (concat [0 1] (map + fib (drop 1 fib)))))
```

Also, in other case where `lazy-seq` is inside `concat` the `rest` is not executed because it is wrapped inside a `lazy-seq` operation which make the whole expression a function to be called in future when next ISeq is requested.

Hopefully this clear up things.

Comment: Wow! That's it! I typed `(take 10 (rest (iterate inc 1)))` and the code works, So I think `rest` is more or less "lazy", but the doc of `rest` did not say it return `lazy sequence`. I think that is the most confusing thing.

Comment: The ISeq (the base of lazy-ness in clojure) is not similar to your IEnumerable (in CLR) or Iterators (in Java). In those things the next method return the next object and hence they have to maintain a state about the current position whereas ISeq next method return a ISeq (not an object) and hence it doesn't need any state. It is like  iterator are : `[1 2 3 4]` , ISeq is `[1 [2 [3 [4 nil]]]]`. This difference is sometimes the reason for confusion